# Avoid Delete-and-Reinsert when updating a compnonent mapped with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Consider the following scenario: A user has a collection of spices, and each spice can either be 'in stock' or 'run out' (denoted by a boolean RunOut property).

I have mapped this relationship with FluentNHibernate using a component like this

```
public UserMappings()
{
   Id(x => x.Id);
   Map(x => x.FirstName);
   Map(x => x.LastName);
   Map(x => x.Email).Length(255).Unique();
   HasOne(x => x.Credentials).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Fetch.Select();
   HasMany(x => x.Spices)
      .Component(c =>
          {
              c.Map(x => x.RunOut);
              c.References(x => x.BaseSpice).Fetch.Join();
          }).Table("User_Spices").Fetch.Join();

}
```

The "Spices" collection in the above mapping is to UserSpice class (a value-object):

```
public class UserSpice
{
    public virtual Spice BaseSpice { get; protected set; }
    public virtual bool RunOut { get; protected set; }

    public static UserSpice Create(Spice baseSpice, bool runOut)
    {
        var userSpice = new UserSpice {BaseSpice = baseSpice, RunOut = runOut};
        return userSpice;
    }
}
```

This works 'fine' - however when I update any of the components (change a spice to RunOut = true, for example), all the user's spices are deleted and re-inserted.

I understand that this is happening because NHibernate has no way of uniquely identifying which user-spice reference it should update.

How can I model this differently to avoid this delete-and-reinsert behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate has different types of collections. Some of them are profiting from more complex mapping like `<list>` or `<idbag>`. Please read this part from documenation about collections types issues:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-mostefficientupdate

*short extract*

> There is, arguably, one more advantage that indexed collections have
>   over sets for many to many associations or collections of values.
>   Because of the structure of an ISet, NHibernate doesn't ever UPDATE a
>   row when an element is "changed". Changes to an ISet always work via
>   INSERT and DELETE (of individual rows). Once again, this consideration
>   does not apply to one to many associations.

So, if you will use indexed list (or even idbag) NHibernate can understand which collection item is changed and can even call UDPATE

And there is another question where you can findout how to map indexed list

[Fluent Nhibernate - Mapping a list results in NullReferenceException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417427)

*short summary:*

> HasMany(x => x.MyChildren).AsList(x =>
>   x.Column("Ordinal")).KeyColumn("AId").Not.KeyNullable();

Comment: Hello Radim, thanks for your answer. I mapped the component with AsList() and specified a key column, and it now works like a treat (I had to recreate all the user spices as the key column was null). Thanks! Can you explain the purpose of the call to .KeyColumn() above? I did not seem to need this.

Comment: Great to hear, you have a progress! The snippet above was an example how to map `<list>` in fluent. if there is special table for children it must contain two columns: ReferenceId to parent (that is the KeyColumn) and *from-0-starting* Index column (mapped AsList()). Please, take a look here, where is the complete example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157820/

Answer (score 1):

implement Equals/GetHashcode in UserSpice with the business rule of uniqueness e.g. BaseSpice equality and add `.AsSet()` to `HasMany(x => x.Spices)`. The Datatype of Spices has to be `ICollection<>` or `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<>` or with a little [extra effort](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/15/using-lt-set-gt-in-mappings-without-iesi-collections-net-4.aspx) `System.Collection.Generic.ISet<>`.

Comment: ThanksFiro. I tried this and the behaviour of NHibernate changed - but not quite to what I need. It now issues a more selective delete statement (e.g. "DELETE FROM User_Spices WHERE  UserAccount_id = 1002 AND RunOut = 0") and only inserts one row back into the table. What distinguishes UserSpice is, basically, the user id and the BaseSpice id. I've implemented this with Equals - but it doesn't work like I hoped. I could make the relationship between User and UserSpice bi-directional, but that doesn't feel right. Any ideas?